# Should @synthesize be used still?

Tags: objective-c

I'm just wondering if @synthesize should still be used even though Xcode does it automatically for properties, simply because it's been done that way for so long?  Or does this mean we can all stop using @synthesize (unless you have a reason to give its instance variable a different name)?

I just want to make sure that from a professional standpoint I'm conforming to good coding practice.

Comment: I don't think this is really an answerable question. Personally, I won't use `@synthesize` unless I have to (there are still a few cases where you do) and though `-Weverything` turns a warning on to detect this, I turn it right back off again. Extra code isn't useful.

Comment: So @StevenFisher, if I understand, it's just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: I guess? I mean, it was made optional for a reason. I really think you should stop using it except in cases where you have to. `-Weverything` includes all sorts of mostly useless things, and I think this is one of them.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate your input.

Comment: @StevenFisher This is a great question, I am glad he asked it. I was just discussing this with a coworker the other day.

Comment: To be clear: I'm not questioning his asking it, I'm just not sure it'll reach a consensus. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. But isn't well known that "good programmers are lazy"? Following that logic, good programmers should agree that less code is always a better thing. ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think. Extra code is harmful, not helpful. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I personally no longer use synthesize for **new development only** *unless required* (see lnafziger's comment below). The reason is because I currently develop for iOS 6, which requires a new version of Xcode, which has the capabilities of auto-including the `@synthesize` during compile time. If I were to do this with old code, there may still be someone in my organization that is using an old version of Xcode (i.e version 4.2) where this would cause problems for them.

So depending on if you still need to be compatible with the older versions of Xcode, this answer will vary. But if you only need to work with new versions of Xcode, you should be fine not declaring `@synthesize`.

Comment: That makes sense.  So, while it has been made optional for the newer version, in a professional setting, I would just have to make it compatible for multiple people to work on?

Comment: Really, those people should be using the latest Xcode as well. :) If you're building an open source library you could sort of justify keeping it compatible, but… I wouldn't.

Comment: You don't have to make it compatible for anyone unless someone is still using an old version of Xcode. Omitting `@synthesize` will cause older versions of Xcode to give compilation errors stating that a `@property` hasn't been synthesized. As long as you don't need to support older versions of Xcode, I see little reason for using `@synthesize`.

Comment: I mostly agree with this (so +1) however, there are situations where you are still required to use @synthesize and don't have a choice (ie when you override the setter and getter of a declared property).  So I would change the wording to say something along the lines of "no longer use it unless it is required"...

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question, I think, skipping `@synthesize` is not unprofessional. Assuming you don't requiring it for some reason (and I'll talk about that), I think it's more professional to write less and cleaner code. `@synthesize` is just noise.

There's a few cases where you might consider it:

1. You need compatibility with the old (32 bit OS X) runtime, or an older version of iOS (pre 4.0).

> Note: Though you might care about 32 bit OS X, I'm not even sure Apple would even accept an app that targets iOS prior to 4.0 now. Certainly, you're going to be really limit yourself.
>
> Your product is a source library you want other developers to be able to use with older versions of Xcode.
>
> You need to use an older version of Xcode (pre 4.4).
>
> You've hit an edge case in the language where `@synthesize` is required. (There's at least one case of this, related to categories.) If you hit this, `@synthesize` that one variable and move on. Don't go back and `@synthesize` everything.
>
> Note that if you turn on `-Weverything` you'll get compiler warnings about this. `-Weverything` includes everything, including some warnings that suggest changes I'd consider ill-advised. This is one of them. Find the appropriate warning switch to turn it back off (it's in the warning message) and do so. :)

See also:

- [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html)

Comment: I've seen a lot of people talk about this "-Weverything"… could you explain what it is for me?

Comment: `-Weverything` is a compiler flag (in Other C Compiler) that not only turns on every single compiler warning, it also turns on all *future* warnings as they're added. The problem with compiler warnings traditionally is that you need to turn them on; if you turn on `-Weverything`, they're all fired and you get to decide which you want to turn off. But you definitely don't want to code around them all. Some of them are beyond pedantic, and actually stray into harmful. So some warnings you want to turn off.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with your ivar being synthesized with `_propertyName` you can safely get rid of the synthesize statements. If you want your ivar to be named something else, you need to include it like so

```
@synthesize propertyName = ________cool_ivar_name
```

Answer (score 1):

There really is no overall correct answer for this. Other than the specified technical reasons given by the other answers (such as tying an alternate ivar name to a property), I feel it is most important to keep consistent with your code. If you are contributing with older libraries that use `@synthesize` all over the place, you might want to stick with it in the name of consistency. Otherwise, if you are starting anew and shooting for the less verbose approach, stick with omitting `@synthesize` as much as possible. I personally like less verbose code, but I value code consistency somewhat more, especially when weeding through thousands of lines of code.